# Is there any way for handling this problem with width and height in css, html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

To create a web game, I decided to make a container class in body. I intend to make all related element in game be relative to this container.

My issues is only related to container class

By default, I suppose in 1920px x 1080px web resolution, The container covers all the body

When the user change width or height or they use other device, The value of width and height in body continuously changes. I don't want it happens in container class.

I set R = 1920/1080 is a root ratio

> if (width/height of body > R) container height gets 100% view height, container width keeps the root ratio.
>
> if (width/height of body < R) container width gets 100% view width, container height keeps the root ratio

I think I need javascript to solve this problem but I don't how to combine them with css. Can you help me?

Comment: Maybe something like [this css ratio trick](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/sass/maintain-aspect-ratio-mixin/) might help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to utilize aspect ratio media queries for this, info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/aspect-ratio)
In conjunction to that, you may be able to utilize min/max-widths and vh/vw units to get the desired scaling without JS.

Here is an example of an aspect ratio using calc and vw. Incase an intrinsic div is something you need aswell:

```css
.ar {
  width: 80%;
  height: calc(80vw / (16 / 9));
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
}
```

```html
<div class="ar"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, That exactly solved my issue in container width, i think i can do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I got it what your question, any here something to help:

```css
.game-container { 
height: 1080px;
position: relative;
width: 1920px;
}

.game-container .content {
height: 100%;
left: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="game-container">
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

In this sample, you can see that `.game-container` start just after `body` with `width: 1920px;` and `height: 1080px;` set on it. Then you have `.content` that has `width: 100%` and `height: 100%`, but as it has `position: absolute` it will relate to it's parent size **.game-container**. In this case you will have a big box with fixed sizes (1980, 1080) and a child that will reflect the same size orientation.

If that is the case I wish that I have help in your path.

Comment: I think my solution is related to ratio in css. Thank you so much.